# how to get the arm instruction disassembly of Global Offset Table (GOT) and plt

Tags: arm, decode, disassembly, objdump, armv8

I am trying to generate the disassembly of dhrystone. The following commands were used:

```
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -O0 -mtune=cortex-a77 -mcpu=cortex-a77 --static -c -DHZ=60 -O2 -fno-inline -fno-pie dhry_1.c
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -O0 -mtune=cortex-a77 -mcpu=cortex-a77 --static -c -DHZ=60 -O2 -fno-inline -fno-pie dhry_2.c
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc -O0 -mtune=cortex-a77 -mcpu=cortex-a77 --static -fno-pie -o dhrystone dhry_1.o dhry_2.o
```

For generating the disassembly, the following command was used:

```
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-objdump -D -x -s -t dhrystone | tee cmdPrint_dhrystone.txt
```

This generates the following file (only small snippets shown here):

```
Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000400270 <.plt>:
  400270:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  400274:   f9400211    ldr x17, [x16]
  400278:   91000210    add x16, x16, #0x0
  40027c:   d61f0220    br  x17
  400280:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  400284:   f9400611    ldr x17, [x16, #8]
  400288:   91002210    add x16, x16, #0x8
  40028c:   d61f0220    br  x17
  400290:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  400294:   f9400a11    ldr x17, [x16, #16]
  400298:   91004210    add x16, x16, #0x10
  40029c:   d61f0220    br  x17
  4002a0:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  4002a4:   f9400e11    ldr x17, [x16, #24]
  4002a8:   91006210    add x16, x16, #0x18
  4002ac:   d61f0220    br  x17
  4002b0:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  4002b4:   f9401211    ldr x17, [x16, #32]
  4002b8:   91008210    add x16, x16, #0x20
  4002bc:   d61f0220    br  x17
  4002c0:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  4002c4:   f9401611    ldr x17, [x16, #40]
  4002c8:   9100a210    add x16, x16, #0x28
  4002cc:   d61f0220    br  x17
  4002d0:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  4002d4:   f9401a11    ldr x17, [x16, #48]
  4002d8:   9100c210    add x16, x16, #0x30
  4002dc:   d61f0220    br  x17
```

If we look at the first 4 lines:

```
  400270:   b00004d0    adrp    x16, 499000 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0xb8>
  400274:   f9400211    ldr x17, [x16]
  400278:   91000210    add x16, x16, #0x0
  40027c:   d61f0220    br  x17
```

we can see a branch instruction going to the address stored in x17 register, which is in *GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE*.

We can find the description of *GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE* in the same file. It provides the following:

```
Disassembly of section .got:

0000000000498f48 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_>:
    ...
  498f50:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498f54:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
    ...
  498f60:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498f64:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498f68:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498f6c:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498f70:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498f74:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498f78:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498f7c:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498f80:   00000060    udf #96
  498f84:   00000000    udf #0
  498f88:   00000010    udf #16
  498f8c:   00000000    udf #0
  498f90:   00000030    udf #48
  498f94:   00000000    udf #0
  498f98:   00000018    udf #24
  498f9c:   00000000    udf #0
  498fa0:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498fa4:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498fa8:   00000050    udf #80
  498fac:   00000000    udf #0
  498fb0:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498fb4:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498fb8:   00000020    udf #32
  498fbc:   00000000    udf #0
  498fc0:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498fc4:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
  498fc8:   00000058    udf #88
  498fcc:   00000000    udf #0
  498fd0:   00000028    udf #40
  498fd4:   00000000    udf #0
  498fd8:   ffb676a0    .inst   0xffb676a0 ; undefined
  498fdc:   ffffffff    .inst   0xffffffff ; undefined
    ...
```

There is no proper instructions defined. Its mostly .inst (undefined).
I would like to know if there is any means to get a meaningful instruction disassembly of the got/plt so that i can sweep through them and know where to go next.

Any suggestions/details will be appreciated. If i am wrong in my understanding, please feel free to correct me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're dumping the raw data in the image file. The load-time fixups haven't been applied. That's why nothing seems to make sense. (Also, the GOT is not code, so it's not meaningful to disassemble it.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you very much for the reply. could you please provide any links that i could follow and apply load time fixups?

Comment: Given that the `objdump` program dumps ELF format files, you probably want to start with documentation on the ELF file format.